Next auth credentials sign in with server actions error handling
I am creating a Next js 14 app, using

shadcn ui
Auth js
Next js server actions

And I'm having trouble handling errors like credential errors on login or sign up
/actions/login.ts


"use server";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { DEFAULT_REDIRECT } from "@/routes";
import { LoginFormSchema, LoginFormSchemaType } from "@/schemas";
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/utils/db/data/user";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { toast } from "sonner";

export const login = async (values: LoginFormSchemaType) => {
  const validatedFields = LoginFormSchema.safeParse(values);
  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return {
      error: true,
      fieldErrors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
      message: "Please verify your data.",
    };
  }

  const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

  const existingUser = await getUserByEmail(email);

  if (!existingUser || !existingUser.email || !existingUser.password) {
    return {
      error: true,
      message: "Invalid email or password.",
    };
  }

  const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
  if (!passwordsMatch) {
    return {
      error: true,
      message: "Invalid email or password.",
    };
  }
  
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirectTo: DEFAULT_REDIRECT,
    });

    toast(`Welcome back ${existingUser.name} `);
    return { success: true, message: "Logged in successfuly" };
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};



/app/(auth)/login/form.tsx


// -----------------------------
  const loginForm = useForm<LoginFormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(LoginFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
  
  // ------------------------
  
   const [formMessage, setFormMessage] = useState<{
    message: string;
    type: "error" | "success";
  } | null>(null);

  const onSubmit = async (values: LoginFormSchemaType) => {
    setFormMessage(null);
    try {
      const response = await login(values);
      console.log("RESPONSE ===> ", response);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("ERROR ===> ", error);

      setFormMessage({
        message: error?.message,
        type: "error",
      });
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <Form {...loginForm}>
      <form onSubmit={loginForm.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="grid gap-4">
        <FormField
          control={loginForm.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  autoComplete="email"
                  disabled={loadingToLogin}
                />
                
//...............



This is the code for both the login server action and the login form, when the response is in the success state, the response comes from the "try" block in the login form and so for the error state. But I want the error to be caught by the "catch" block to render different data like the form error message, is there a correct way to do do ?

I'm running into the same problem, and had to solve it forcing the redirect to false, and returning the response back to the client, where I then did a router.push('path-to-home'). Did you ever manage to figure out the error handling for [auth][error] CredentialsSignin?
